# (Revised) Prove that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism and find the kernel.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Quoting " Let $\phi : \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z$ be given by $\phi(n) = 7n$. Prove that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism. Find the kernel, and the image of $\phi$."

My understanding:

**Part 1:**

Given $n,m \in \Bbb Z$, let's check that $\phi(n+m) =\phi(n)+\phi(m)$

$$\phi(n+m) = 7(n+m) = 7n + 7m = \phi(n)+\phi(m)$$

Therefore as the group operation in $\phi$ is preserved, $\phi$ is a group homomorphism.

**Part 2 (revised):**

- $\phi$ is one-to-one as:  $\space \space \phi (n) = \phi(m) \Rightarrow 7n =7m \Rightarrow n=m  $. We also know that $\phi(e)=e$ by the property of homomorphism. Therefore, no other object than $0$ in the domain can map to $0$ in the codomain. It follows that:
  $$\ker(\phi)=\{ x \in \Bbb Z : \phi(x)=e\}=\{e\}$$

**Part 3 (revised):**

I claim that the only possible image-elements of $\phi$ are the multiples of $7$ in $\mathbb Z$ denoted $7\mathbb Z$.

To prove this I have to show that Im$(\phi) \subset 7 \Bbb Z$ and that $ 7 \Bbb Z \subset $ Im$(\phi)$.

Proving Im$(\phi) \subset 7 \Bbb Z$
:

- $\forall y \in $ Im$(\phi)$ such that $  y =\phi(x)$ where $x \in 7 \Bbb Z$. It follows that $y \in 7 \Bbb Z$, therefore Im$(\phi) \subset 7 \Bbb Z$

Proving $ 7 \Bbb Z \subset $ Im$(\phi)$:

- $\forall y \in  7\Bbb Z$ such that $  y =7x$ where $x \in \phi(x)$. It follows that $y \in \phi(x)$, therefore $ 7 \Bbb Z \subset $ Im$(\phi)$.

Any input to my understanding is much appreciated.

Comment: $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}, \phi(n) = 7n$ is not a bijection, so it does not have an inverse.

Comment: There is no need to talk about inverse maps.  Just show that $\textrm{Image}(\phi) = 7\mathbb{Z}$ by showing that each set is a subset of the other.

Comment: For part 2, you're right but it's a little confusing to refer to the identity elements of the domain and codomain as $e_1$ and $e_2$.  Just call them both $0$ like a normal person.

Comment: Who advised to re-post? That's a no-no in general. Reposting is ok, if the first version still made sense as a question, received answers, and well after that you realize that you really wanted to ask something else. Your first question has no answer, so it is better to edit it.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I've merged your posts. I've done so, because the other one was closed as a duplicate. If you do mind it, please roll-back the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It started to become a headache.

Comment: Don't worry, things usually aren't as tyrannic as they may seem right now; just remember: thou shalt not create duplicates, and you'll do fine! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first part is correct, in the second you can write $ker(\phi) = \{e\}$.

About the image - you can show that $im(\phi) = 7 \Bbb Z$ by double inclusion.

Comment: What does  "double inclusion" stand for?

Comment: $im(\phi) \subset 7 \Bbb Z$ and $7 \Bbb Z \subset im(\phi)$ @gegu

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is a group homomorphism, and it is injective, therefore its kernel is trivial.

For part $3$, the goal is to show that $\operatorname{Im}\phi = 7\mathbb Z$.

Given an integer $k$, its image is $7k$, a member of $7\mathbb Z$, so $\operatorname{Im}\phi \subseteq 7\mathbb Z$

Given an integer $n=7k \in 7\mathbb Z$, there's the integer $k\in \mathbb Z$, the image of which is $7k$, therefore $7\mathbb Z \subseteq \operatorname{Im}\phi$.