# (Revised) Let $\phi : \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z$ be given by $\phi(n) = 7n$. Find the image of $\phi$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Quoting " Let $\phi : Z \rightarrow Z$ be given by $\phi(n) = 7n$. [...] Find the image of $\phi$."

My understanding (revised):

I claim that the only possible image-elements of $\phi$ are the multiples of 7 in z denoted 7Z.

To prove this I have to show that Im$(\phi) \subset 7 \Bbb Z$ and that $ 7 \Bbb Z \subset $ Im$(\phi)$.

Proving Im$(\phi) \subset 7 \Bbb Z$
:

- $\forall y \in $ Im$(\phi)$ such that $  y =\phi(x)$ where $x \in 7 \Bbb Z$. It follows that $y \in 7 \Bbb Z$. Therefore, Im$(\phi) \subset 7 \Bbb Z$

Proving $ 7 \Bbb Z \subset $ Im$(\phi)$:

- $\forall y \in  7\Bbb Z$ such that $  y =7x$ where $x \in \phi(x)$. It follows that $y \in \phi(x)$. Therefore, $ 7 \Bbb Z \subset $ Im$(\phi)$.

Any input to my understanding is much appreciated.

Comment: same exact question asked yesterday, by **you** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236143/prove-that-phi-is-a-group-homomorphism-find-the-kernel-and-the-image

Comment: It is perhaps better, to edit the original question, instead of producing duplicate questions.

Comment: Thx for the input on "repost". I understand my mistake. it created confusion. I did a complete revision of both questions. They are no longer duplicates. I wish we could focus back on the **revised** question and ...